# Issues installing package on Raspberry 2

Tags: ros-indigo, raspberrypi, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I installed ROS Indigo on my raspberry 2 and im trying to get the camera to a ros node using this:  https://github.com/fpasteau/raspicam_node
My main issue actually is that i cant install the packages: ros-groovy-image-transport ros-groovy-image-transport-plugins ros-groovy-camera-info-manager

As im on indigo, i tried to change the name of packages from groovy to indigo like this: ros-indigo-image-transport but with no succes.
So i tried to get them manually by downloading them to the src folder and compiling them. But i stuck on dependencies like "Theodora".
I tried the roslocate/rosinstall way with no succes.

So, has the author of raspicam_node seems to install easily this packages, i wonder if I'm missing something. How can i know if their is (or not) this package available for Raspberry Pi 2 with Indigo?

Thanks !
If you have any hint, thanks again ! :)

---

Update:

Rosdep doesnt seem to find source:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ rosdep install image-transport
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource image-transport
```

With the roslocate:

```
roslocate info image-transport >  image-transport.rosinstall
Using ROS_DISTRO: indigo
Not found via rosdistro - falling back to information provided by rosdoc
error contacting http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/image-transport/stack.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
error contacting http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/image-transport/manifest.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
cannot locate information about image-transport
```

I think their is  an error with the URL it try to use:
http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/image-transport/manifest.yaml redirect to: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/image-transport/manifest.yaml and get a 404 error
The url it should use is probably: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/image_transport/manifest.yaml
Just image**-**transport that change to image**_**transport

Same thing for camera-info-manager, all - become _

Wrong url: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/camera-info-manager/

Goog url: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/camera_info_manager/

It's weird, i didnt block on this yesterday :/

How can i repair this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213425/issues-installing-package-on-raspberry-2/) by [Amrac](https://answers.ros.org/users/23079/amrac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2015-07-11**:
Could you please be a little more specific with your commands? It would greatly help us figure out the best way to assist if we knew more. What does the rosinstall command output? Have you tried `rosdep install image-transport`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that pesky underscore.

```
allenh1@tuxbox $ rosdep what-needs image_transport
compressed_depth_image_transport
image_rotate
image_proc
rviz
image_view
compressed_image_transport
camera_info_manager
rqt_image_view
theora_image_transport
polled_camera
stereo_image_proc
depth_image_proc
```

You should be able to run `rosdep install image_transport` and get these resolved.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1